# logger configuration to log to file

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, filehandler

Python newbie. Now I have been stuck around this for a while. When I try to write logs in a file using `ini` configuration nothing is captured in the file. I tried to debug the problem but couldn't get any clue. Writing logs without using `ini` file works perfectly fine.

Below is the code and ini file

```
import logging

from logging.config import fileConfig

def info(message):


    fileConfig('logging_config.ini')
    logger=logging.getLogger("simple logger")

    logger.warning('Something is not right')
    logger.warning(message)
```

logging_config.ini

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=file_handler

[logger_root]
level=WARNING
handlers=file_handler

[formatters]
keys=formatter

[formatter_formatter]
format='%(message)s'

[handler_file_handler]
class=FileHandler
level=WARNING
formatter=formatter
args=('dummyoutput.log','w')
```

I checked the logger object also to see if I can get any clue from its properties. Below is the object

```
{'disabled': 0,
 'filters': [],
 'handlers': [<logging.FileHandler object at 0x7ff03358ce90>],
 'level': 30,
 'name': 'root',
 'parent': None,
 'propagate': 1}
```

Not sure if its helpful but I noticed the property `disabled` was earlier shown `TRUE` but now it is `0` every time.

Has anyone got any clue on this?

**Update:** The issue was due to multiple calls to logging.config.fileConfig() for the same configuration file. But I couldn't really understand why nothing was written when that function was called for the last time. Any idea on that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what the (stupid) mistake was. Actually the `info(message)` was getting called more than once and so was `fileConfig()` for the same configuration file as it was inside `info` function. Hence, the issue. Modified code as below and it worked.

```
import logging
from logging.config import fileConfig

def info(message):

    logger.warning('Something is not right')
    logger.warning(message)

fileConfig('logging_config.ini')
logger=logging.getLogger("simple.logger")
```

**Update:** Even if we don't follow the logger naming convention for eg. as I gave `simple logger` instead of `simple.logger` it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

There is a naming convention for loggers, and the name "simple logger" is not valid because of the space.

You should replace the space by a period. We usually use Python package names for loggers.

Here is how you can fix that:

```
import logging

from logging.config import fileConfig


def info(message):

    fileConfig('logging_config.ini')
    logger = logging.getLogger("simple.logger")

    logger.warning('Something is not right')
    logger.warning(message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    info("hello")
```

It woks perfectly.

```
'Something is not right'
'hello'
```

Quoting Logger Objects:

> The name is potentially a period-separated hierarchical value, like `foo.bar.baz` (though it could also be just plain `foo,` for example). Loggers that are further down in the hierarchical list are children of loggers higher up in the list. For example, given a logger with a name of `foo`, loggers with names of `foo.bar`, `foo.bar.baz`, and `foo.bam` are all descendants of `foo`. The logger name hierarchy is analogous to the Python package hierarchy, and identical to it if you organise your loggers on a per-module basis using the recommended construction `logging.getLogger(__name__)`. That’s because in a module, `__name__` is the module’s name in the Python package namespace.

Comment: Oh yes...you're right. But with that also its not working. Also, I tried earlier mostly without giving logger any name `logger = logging.getLogger()` but that also didn't worked. No idea whats going wrong there.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what's not working (because I have tested it). Note: you should use a full path in your config INI. Have you found your log file?

Comment: The log file was already being generated. The code you shared is perfectly fine. Actually the problem was that the `info(message)` was getting called more than once and so was `fileConfig()` for the same configuration file as it was inside info function *[please check my answer below for details]*. But I couldn't really understand why nothing was written when that function was called for the last time. Any idea on that??